# How to select an appropriate value for step in predict_generator?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So I have built a convolutional neural network in Keras for classification. I am loading the training, validation and testing images from the **flow_from_directory** function in **ImageDataGenerator** package in keras. I am able to train the neural network perfectly and I am using the **predict_generator** function to predict the class labels for my test images (79,726  images).

So my code looks like this:

```
network_output=model.predict_generator(test_set,steps=79726 ,verbose=1)
```

The output of the network is basically probabilities for each of my 10 classes. So the dimension of `network_output` should be 79726 rows and 10 columns, however, the actual dimensions of `network_output` is 255074 rows and 10 columns. Which is more outputs than it should be ! I found the number of output changes with `steps` parameter. How can I select the value of step to get the correct number of outputs.

Please let me know in the comments/answer section if further clarifications/ code is needed to explain the problem better.

Edit: here is the network structure: input_size is32

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten,BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D 
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, input_shape = (input_size, input_size, 3),activation = 'relu'))      
model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation = 'relu'))       
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3,  activation = 'relu'))
​model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

​